# Can supplying DC power into an AC device break the device?

Tags: ac, dc

I have an [AC device](http://www.hydropath.com/products/hydroflow-hs38) that takes 12 volts 47-63Hz AC. It is a water softner that is essentially an electromagnet. I lost the original plug and supplied it with 11.2V DC, it came on for a few minutes and no longer turns on.

Did the DC current break my AC device or is the DC power source broken?

Comment: Did you test the DC power source on a different, known-to-be-working device? We could speculate endlessly but if you do this simple test, the problem is effectively divided in two...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be broken. Supplying ac to an electromagnet can produce an ac current of maybe a few hundred milli-amps. Supplying the same coil with DC could cause the coil to take a high current of several amps. This could easily burn-out the coil after a few minutes.

But, it could be the DC power source that broke - you need to test it with a voltmeter. If you don't have one then you need to find someone who can do this for you.

Once you have a voltmeter, check to see if it can measure resistance and connect it to the AC device to see if you can measure resistance between the two terminals. If it measures a few ohms then the ac device is probably ok - this should be confirmed byt the output of dc power source being open circuit or low voltage.

Answer (score 1):

From first impressions, the device appears to be an inductor coil electromagnet.

If this is so, the device would provide a given reactance to AC power, and as with any inductor, a lower reactance / resistance to DC. In effect, the coil would act like a short circuit (or at least a near-short) to DC power.

The possibilities are:

- Due to insufficient reactance, too much current flowed through the device, and damaged it.
- Due to insufficient reactance, the DC supply was forced to supply more current than designed for, and either blew a fuse or got otherwise damaged.

To arrive at a more definitive answer, a multimeter could be used to test the power supply output, at the least.

Further, one wouldn't supply DC to the system and expect it to operate, in the past or going forward.

Comment: what is reactance?

Comment: @david_adler Effective impedance to the provided voltage. Reactance is the AC equivalent of a DC circuit's resistance. It varies with frequency of the AC, increasing with increase in frequency for an inductor, and decreasing with increase in frequency for a capacitor. Simplification: The current drawn by a device is determined by Ohm's Law, `I = V / R`, so higher the reactance, lower the current for a given voltage.

Answer (score 1):

In general, It completely depends on the device you are using. It may be that the device has an AC adapter, because the AC adaptor was cheaper to source, and it has a bridge rectifier to turn the AC into DC inside. Or it may be that the device actually uses or needs AC power on the inside. You won't know unless you have detailed information about the device, such as a schematic or opening it up to take a look.

For your specific device, it seems it needed the AC current. Without checking your power supply, or the device for blown parts, or getting the correct adaptor to test with, there is no way to tell if your device has been permanently broken.